# Что делать с файлом имяпроекта.v12.suo GIT

Tags: c#, visual-studio, git, visual-studio-2013, git-commit

У меня есть проект, я его закомитил и создал новую ветку потом поработал в ней и закомитил ещё раз чтоб вернуться в основную ветку. Потом вернулся в основную ветку, в VS попросило нажать reload я жму, и потом пишу `git status`. Мне показывает что мой файл имяпроекта.v12.suo modified. Тоже самое происходит когда я возвращаюсь обратно в новую ветку, опять имяпроекта.v12.suo modified, тоесть чтоб переключаться между ветками мне приходится дополнять коммит `git commit --amend`. Что с этим делать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте `*.suo` в `.gitignore`.

Файлы `.suo` содержат состояние открытых панелей Visual Studio и тому подобные вещи, интересные только на локальной машине. В репозитории им не место.

---

Вот большой список того, что должно быть в .gitignore для проектов под Visual Studio: https://www.gitignore.io/api/visualstudio